# Is it possible to create a fixed-duration trim window when editing video in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I am using UIImagePickerController as in the following code. The editing view shows a trimming window, which you can drag either the beginning or the ending. I'd like to be able to create a fixed duration trimming window that you can slide around.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or does anyone know of a custom control to achieve this? Or can you suggest an approach to create this myself (if it isn't too complicated)?

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;


    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gathered that if you want to create a fixed window trim editing controller, you'll need to code it from scratch. There are no options in UIImagePickerController to fix the window size.